# Finding origin extension

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm just starting my adventure with programming and VBA and now I have small problem. Sometimes people change extension of files (they have some reasons) but I need to find extension before changing.

For example: first it was `doc` , then `docm`, then `odt` (or `pdf`, etc.) and I need to find that it was `doc` at the beginning. I don't know if it's possible.

I thought that if I open file in notepad there is some kind of code in it, and probably part of code may be "origin" extension, but which part is it? Or is there some other way I could use in VBA?

Comment: Why is it important to find the original extension?  If I "save as" an Excel file to create a PDF then it's not even the same file, but a new one, and the old one is still there...

Comment: I try to make a tool to repair documents, and I assumed that files can be corrupted also by having improper extension (done purposely or not),So I thought I need origin extension to repair this. If file is "saved as" so the extension in file code should  be changed to chosen one. But if extension is changed by user, or through opening by improper program, then in my opinion somwhere in code should be a sign of extension the file will work properly with.

Answer (score 0):

Please Look into @Tim Williams comments, it is not prudent to try to find origin's extension as many a times files are saved in different file formats. However various approaches for keeping track of file version and history of the files are mentioned here-under.
There are some tools(example-XLTools) and processes that will allow you to see the revisions of an Excel sheet. As far as a revision history within the Excel sheet, you will not have any unless you have set this up yourself. There is not a built in change history for Excel. Otherwise File History regularly backs up versions of your files in the Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos, and Desktop folders and the OneDrive files available offline on your PC. Over time, you'll have a complete history of your files. If the originals are lost, damaged, or deleted, you can restore them. You can also browse and restore different versions of your files. For example, if you want to restore an older version of a file (even if it wasn't deleted or lost), you can browse through a timeline, select the version you want, and restore it.

If your files are uploaded to SharePoint and If a list or library on your site tracks versions, you can view version history for items or files, providing you have Read permission to the list or library. The version history contains information about when the item or file was changed, who changed it, and information about what was changed. In libraries, the version history might also contain comments written by the people who made changes.

You can view version history in either of two ways:

In the list or library on your site

In the Microsoft Office Backstage view of a Microsoft Office 2010 document.    You can also track changes if you upload to DropBox Or say Box, there also revision history and version changes can be tracked.